# How can read a string and make it into different substring?

Tags: c++, string, substring

I have a 2 RNA chain: 1 G-enyzme and 1 U.C-Enyzme and break it up with a slash if you see a G  in G enzyme and u or c if u for u.c-enyzme and vice versa meaning you can use u or c for the G-enyzme after and  g for the u.c-enyzmes i looked up several code on breaking substring like substr which only get from 1 position till end. Is there any other way i can possible do this?

Example:
G-enyzme "AUCG, AUG, G, CU...."

Output: = AUC / G , AU/G , G , CU

if there is no G make it string end, so CU is end chain

```
int main()
{
    string G_enyzme = "AUCG,AUG,G,CU,ACUAUACG";
    string U_C_enyzme = "GGAC,U,AU,GAU,C,U,AC,GC,AU";
    size_t g = G_enyzme.find('G');
    if(g != string::npos)  //if G position is found
    {
        //put a slash between AUC and G , AU and G, .... , ACUAUAC and G 
        //if the substring does not have G make it begin / end

    }
}
```

Comment: _like substr which only get from 1 position till end._ [std::string::substr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) can get substring of arbitrary length, starting at arbitrary position, not just until the end of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question needs more clarification. I will cover the first case and leave the rest up to you since this

> "and u or c if u for u.c-enyzme and vice versa"

is not clear to me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string getStr(const std::string& str, const char& flag)
{
    std::string temp;
    // G-enyzme
    if ( flag == 'G' ){
        for ( int i(0); i < str.size(); ++i ){
            temp += str[i];
            if ( str[i] == 'G' ){
                temp.pop_back();
                temp += "/G";
            }
        }
    }
    //  U.C-Enyzme 
    if ( flag == 'U' ){
        //TODO  
    }
    return temp;
}


int main()
{
    std::string str ("AUCG, AUG, G, CU, ACUAUACG");
    std::cout << str         << std::endl;
    std::cout << getStr(str,'G') << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and the output is

```
AUCG, AUG, G, CU, ACUAUACG
AUC/G, AU/G, /G, CU, ACUAUAC/G
```

Comment: @darkflames363, I don't have c++14.